# Exclude multiple characters in regex

Tags: java, regex

How do I exclude multiple characters at once.

I need to write regex that can check if a java multi-line comment has no end.

For example two comments

```
/* some comment */
```

and

```
/* Multi line comment start
```

The regex code must match the 2nd comment but not the first.

I tried something like

```
\/\*(.*)[^\*\/]
```

but this only excludes one character. How do I exclude two at once.

Comment: Are you using Java?

Comment: Yes. I am writing a program that takes a java file and searches for all the comments inside.

Comment: Will the program be written in Java?

Comment: Yes. I already wrote the code for a regular // comment and a /* */ and now am struggling with the multiline comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the `*` quantifier on `.(?!\*\/)`:

```
^\/\*(?:.(?!\*\/))*$
```

This means that it will match anything as long as there isn't `*/` after the thing to match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sq5aSn/1)

However, this takes quite a lot of steps. If I were you, I would have just matched comments both with and without `*/` and put the `*/` part in a group. If that group exists, then it's with an end, otherwise the comment has no end.

Comment: It doesn't look for a multi-line comment. You [restricted it to one line.](https://regex101.com/r/sq5aSn/2) Your second workaround is valid though.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR, it's not possible

Because you have no idea how many lines should be matched when facing with an unclosed multi-line comment block. Because you don't have any idea whether or not `/*` is placed inside a string literal or ending `*/` delimiter is. But if you want to match one line (current line) where `/*` resides in its beginning you could do this:

```
(?m)^\h*/\*(?!(?>(?!/\*)[\s\S])*\*/).*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/W9nZoQ/1)

Breakdown:

- `(?m)` Enable multi-line modifier
- `^` Assert start of line
- `\h*` Match horizental whitespaces (if any)
- `/\*` Match beginning of a multi-line comment block
- `(?!` Start of a negative lookahead

  - `(?>` Start of an atomic grouping

    - `(?!/\*)` If next two characters are not /*
    - `[\s\S]` Match next character
  - `)*` Repeat as many as possible
  - `\*/` Match end of block
- `)` End of negative lookahead
- `.*` Match every thing in current line

Java code:

```
String regex = "(?m)^\\h*/\\*(?!((?!/\\*)[\\s\\S])*\\*/).*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

[Java live demo](https://ideone.com/58szgA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookbehind to assert that `*/` isn't preceding the end of the line :

```
^\/\*.*(?<!\*\/)$
```

See this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M0vyfG/2).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
\/\*\s*((?!\*\/|\/\*)[\s\S])*(?=\/\*|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/25)

```
             \/\*\s*    :  matching the start of multi-line comment
          (?=\/\*|$)    :  ending pattern (new comment start \/* or end of the text $ )
((?!\*\/|\/\*)[\s\S])*  :  stop present matching process and start new one when meets */ or \/*
```

[Test sample text]

```
/* some c
omment */
/* Multi line comment start
 fdsafdsa
/*

/* fds

sa */

/* fjdslajfdl 

/*fjdl  */  /* fjdls
fjdls
/*  */   /*fdls
jfdla*/  /* fdlsajfl

fdsa
/*end*/
```